# No Border around Textfield - React Material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

i use Material UI Theming. When i added my Theme with create Theme, it deletes all Borders around the input fields:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpBuY.png

Here is my Theme:

```
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';

declare module '@mui/material/styles' {
  interface Theme {}
}

const theme = createTheme({
  // modify colors
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#3f51b5',
    },
    secondary: {
      main: '#ff3d00',
    },
  },
  /* weitere Farben: error: warning, info, success */
  // modify Schriftart
  typography: {
    fontFamily: [
      '-apple-system',
      'BlinkMacSystemFont',
      '"Segoe UI"',
      'Roboto',
      '"Helvetica Neue"',
      'Arial',
      'sans-serif',
      '"Apple Color Emoji"',
      '"Segoe UI Emoji"',
      '"Segoe UI Symbol"',
    ].join(','),
  },
});

export default theme;
```

And here is my Theme Provider:

```
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core';
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
      </Provider>
    </ThemeProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer: There was an false import of the ThemeProvider in the index.tsx.

Her is the correct one:

```
import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material';
```

Answer (score 0):

Export your theme providerto import it in main file

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).